# Xcode/clang: Why do some, not all, of my headers give "warning: no rule to process file xxx for architecture arm7"

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, linker-warning

I am building an iOS 5 app with ARC using clang on Xcode 4.2/Lion. Good practice for me is to try to get rid of as many warnings as possible but I'm lost on this one. The app has quite a few classes, but a limited number of their header files (8 or 9) give linker warnings like this:

```
warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/TKMyClass.h' of type sourcecode.objj.h for architecture arm7`
```

I don't see any significant commonalities across these headers: a couple are 3rd party OSS code; the rest are all my own. One is a plain-C header file (with no corresponding .c) containing nothing but constants, `#defines` and enums; a couple are `UIView` and `UIViewController` subclasses created with Xcode's templates; the rest are ordinary Obj-C classes, some of which inherit from `NSObject` and some of which don't. All (of my classes) were created from scratch within the project at various times. Both older and newer classes give no warnings.

My project uses a mix of C++, Objective-C++ and Objective C classes. The warning-generating classes here are mostly Objective C (their implementations are in .m files) but the two 3rd party classes are implemented in Objective C++ (.mm).

The project otherwise builds fine and runs in the simulator and on iDevices.

To my shame I'm not particularly familiar with the project settings pages in Xcode. I expect the solution is contained in there somewhere but I'm not sure where to start without breaking things.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That means that you have accidentally added header files to be compiled. You need to go into your projects `Build Phases` and remove all header files from the `Compile Sources` section.

Comment: the weird thing (for me) is that xcode adds them itself when adding a new file to the project via the wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Architecture (Project and Target): Standard (armv7) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT) and go to Build Pharse (Compile Source) and cheek there should not be any .h file added there.